# Cloudant to PouchDB replication with a proxy

Tags: couchdb, cloudant, replicate, pouchdb

I am using PouchDB and am trying to replicate from a cloudant server.
I also have a nodejs app that proxies the requests to cloudant using the technique described [here](https://cloudant.com/blog/cors-and-reverse-proxies-in-node-js-express)

```
var request = require('request')

module.exports = function(pattern, host){
  return function(req, res, next){
    if(req.url.match(pattern)){
      var db_path = req.url.match(pattern)[1]
        , db_url = [host, db_path].join('/');
      req.pipe(request[req.method.toLowerCase()](db_url)).pipe(res);
    }else{
      next();
    }
  }
}


app.use(forward(/\/db\/(.*)/, TARGET_URL));
```

I am calling replicate on my pouchdb like this:

```
db.replicate.from('http://localhost/db/myDb', {continuous: true})
```

Looking in the network tab the first request succeeds, however subsequent requests are made, but instead of calling `http://localhost/db/myDb` they are going to `http://localhost/db` and thus result in a 404. For some reason it has dropped the name of my database.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

Just try Smileupps. It's a free [couchdb hosting](https://www.smileupps.com) service supporting the latest version of CouchDB(1.6.0), compatible with PouchDB as well.

Comment: Thanks I did end up using couch happy actually!

Answer (score 0):

there is some logic that assumes a host/dbname setup, for how you could use a `http://localhost/db_myDb` name setup by changing the last line of your app to `app.use(forward(/\/db\_(.*)/, TARGET_URL));` though there are some other issues that PouchDB has at the current version with cloudant

Answer (score 0):

I've heard at least one person say that they found success by syncing PouchDB <-> CouchDB <-> Cloudant.  PouchDB offers 1st-class support for CouchDB and IrisCouch; for other providers like Cloudant or Couchbase Sync Gateway, we're working on it.